# Why is there a difference in the response depending on the formats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm trying to access [Goodreads API that sends me information about books](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show_by_isbn). I would particularly like to obtain the "Shelves". When I access them through [the url](https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/0380795272?key=pU8aWDMPyBMZ45ObUtZyg) I have no problem.

```
<GoodreadsResponse>
...
<authors>
<author>
<id>18</id>
<name>Gary Paulsen</name>
<role/>
<image_url nophoto="false">
<![CDATA[
https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1309159225p5/18.jpg
]]>
</image_url>
<small_image_url nophoto="false">
<![CDATA[
https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1309159225p2/18.jpg
]]>
</small_image_url>
<link>
<![CDATA[
https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/18.Gary_Paulsen
]]>
</link>
<average_rating>3.77</average_rating>
<ratings_count>427417</ratings_count>
<text_reviews_count>30355</text_reviews_count>
</author>
</authors>
<reviews_widget>
<![CDATA[
<style> #goodreads-widget { font-family: georgia, serif; padding: 18px 0; width:565px; } #goodreads-widget h1 { font-weight:normal; font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB596; margin-bottom: 0; } #goodreads-widget a { text-decoration: none; color:#660; } iframe{ background-color: #fff; } #goodreads-widget a:hover { text-decoration: underline; } #goodreads-widget a:active { color:#660; } #gr_footer { width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #BBB596; text-align: right; } #goodreads-widget .gr_branding{ color: #382110; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } </style> <div id="goodreads-widget"> <div id="gr_header"><h1><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50.Hatchet">Hatchet Reviews</a></h1></div> <iframe id="the_iframe" src="https://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_widget_iframe?did=DEVELOPER_ID&amp;format=html&amp;isbn=0689840926&amp;links=660&amp;min_rating=&amp;review_back=fff&amp;stars=000&amp;text=000" width="565" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe> <div id="gr_footer"> <a class="gr_branding" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50.Hatchet?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=reviews_widget">Reviews from Goodreads.com</a> </div> </div>
]]>
</reviews_widget>
<popular_shelves>
<shelf name="to-read" count="42731"/>
<shelf name="currently-reading" count="4063"/>
<shelf name="young-adult" count="2452"/>
<shelf name="fiction" count="1960"/>
<shelf name="adventure" count="1052"/>
<shelf name="favorites" count="1027"/>
<shelf name="classics" count="909"/>
<shelf name="ya" count="832"/>
```

But when I try to access it by code (`goodreads.py`), I only get a part of the response I received through the URL.

Here is the code of `goodreads.py`:

```
#get every books from the csv file

# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data = pd.read_csv("books.csv", nrows=10)
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
print(data.head())

for i,row in data.iterrows():
    res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn", params={"isbn": data['isbn'][i], "user_id": 49393496, "format":"json"})
    parsed = json.loads(res.text)
    print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))

print(data.head())
```

And here is the answer of the terminal:

```
(col_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\collective_intelligence>python goodreads.py
         isbn                  title            author  year
0  0380795272  Krondor: The Betrayal  Raymond E. Feist  1998
1  1416949658     The Dark Is Rising      Susan Cooper  1973
2  1857231082     The Black Unicorn       Terry Brooks  1987
3  0553803700               I, Robot      Isaac Asimov  1950
4  080213825X           Four Blondes  Candace Bushnell  2000
{'reviews_widget': '<style>\n  #goodreads-widget {\n    font-family: georgia, serif;\n    padding: 18px 0;\n    width:565px;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget h1 {\n    font-weight:normal;\n    font-size: 16px;\n    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB596;\n    margin-bottom: 0;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget a {\n    text-decoration: none;\n    color:#660;\n  }\n  iframe{\n    background-color: #fff;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }\n  #goodreads-widget a:active {\n    color:#660;\n  }\n  #gr_footer {\n    width: 100%;\n    border-top: 1px solid #BBB596;\n    text-align: right;\n  }\n  #goodreads-widget .gr_branding{\n    color: #382110;\n    font-size: 11px;\n    text-decoration: none;\n    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n</style>\n<div id="goodreads-widget">\n  <div id="gr_header"><h1><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92918.Krondor">Krondor Reviews</a></h1></div>\n  <iframe id="the_iframe" src="https://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_widget_iframe?did=DEVELOPER_ID&amp;format=html&amp;isbn=0380795272&amp;links=660&amp;review_back=fff&amp;stars=000&amp;text=000" width="565" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>\n  <div id="gr_footer">\n    <a class="gr_branding" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/92918.Krondor?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=reviews_widget">Reviews from Goodreads.com</a>\n  </div>\n</div>\n'}
```

I only have `reviews_widget`.

Why is there a difference in the response depending on the formats?

How to obtain all the results of the application and especially the shelves?

Comment: Your code requests a different url than the one you linked.

Comment: what's in the CSV file, can you share a snippet?

Comment: @Tryph Yes, sorry. I changed it to the right one

Comment: @iAmTryingOK It is provided in the last snippet

Comment: When you say "by URL", do you mean through your browser? The difference in user agent might be significant.

Comment: It's hard to say *what* the first URL is requesting, since all the details you provide in the body of the request from your code appear to be obscured by a reference to some server-side key.

Comment: The request you're making is using url encoded parameters. If you go to the same URL via a browser, you only get the reviews_widget as well. https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn?isbn=0380795272&user_id=49393496&format=json

Comment: @chepner, I meant going straight to `https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn/0380795272?key=pU8aWDMPyBMZ45ObUtZyg` through the url space of my browser. I adapted the exemple from the docs which I have linked. The server-side key is only necessary to retrieve the data in the XML format.

Comment: Looking at it again, the API endpoint you're using is labeled "Get the reviews for a book given an ISBN". I think the reviews_widget is all you should be getting.

Comment: URL: https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/list.xml is what you should use to get shelf information, it takes developer key, user ID and page number as params

Comment: @Holloway So how can I get the `<popular_shelves>` that follows in the request that retrieves XML?

Comment: if you use `format=xml` it seems to return the full data. Weird API but you could use that and parse the xml instead of JSON. (you need to use the `key` as well)

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in their API page, but it may be in there somewhere. At this point this isn't really a programming question, though. You might have better luck on the [Goodreads Developers group](https://www.goodreads.com/group/show/8095-goodreads-developers).

Comment: @iAmTryingOK And _extra permission_ according to [the related docs](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#list.book). Any method to reach the popular shelves through the XML ?

Comment: Look at the docs for Python xml parsing [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)